# Asp.net core thread safe global variable

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a .net core razor app that has a special use case where I need to have a global counter that will be incremented by every request, and yet it should remain thread-safe.

Also at web application load, this counter will be read from a database using entity framework.

I don't think that static variables are threadsafe for this scenario (since it can be read by a request then be modified after another request read its previous value)

So I was wondering if a locking mechanism is needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are reading counter from the database I assume every request would increment value and save it in the database? I prefer to use locking in this case.

This might be a naive solution, but this is how I tackle it:

```cs
private static object _requestLock = new object();

public string UpdateCounter()
{
  // it can be as well Config table with lots of different records and one of them would be Counter value
  var counter = _dbContext.Counters.FirstOfDefault();

  lock (_requestLock)
  {
    counter.Value++;
  }

  _dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I dont get the part of "_requestLock = new object();"  you are instantiating requestlock to an empty object ?

Comment: [You can decide which thing to lock on. Its common to use private static object, but some people are using readonly property or even `this`](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/threads/lockchoice.html)